# Can't Consume POST request but Dev Console shows url is being hit with requests

Tags: apex, rest-api, post

Afternoon,

We have a vendor that is trying to send POST requests to a method in we have hosted using `Site Guest User`.

Here is our code snippet that we are using to see if the request is even entering the method, but it is not.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myUrl/*')
global without sharing class myClass {

    @HttpPost
    global static String createSomething(String value) {

    System.Debug(value); 

}
```

The url format is passing the data in a key value pair format.

`/myUrl?Id=123&Name=Test&Age=40`

The issue is that we can see in the debug logs that we are getting the requests, but the method will not fire. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The format of the HTTP request needs to correspond to your Apex REST method. If your method is annotated with `@HttpPost` and the signature of the method has a single String argument named `value`, your request needs to be a POST with a payload (request body) that looks like this:

```js
{
"value": "..."
}
```

Comment: What if it's not coming as JSON, x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: To be clear we are the ones consuming the post, not sending the post.

Comment: If it's not coming as JSON or it's coming in as JSON but you want to parse it yourself, you would need a different implementation [along these lines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_restrequest.htm)

Comment: The odd thing is that if we take away the parameter in the method, the url will not be hit by the vendor's post request. If we have a parameter, we can see the Post Request and it's key-value pairs sent in the URL, but the method will not fire. It's almost as if the class is being run but the method is not.

Comment: Both cases have the same root cause - the request doesn't match method signature.

Comment: How do you set the method signature? The article you posted above doesn't seem to provide an answer.